# How to make sure the QApplication and its QThreads are all closed

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

The code below creates a single `QDialog` which starts a `QThread` that gets a function that is long to calculate. QDialog's `closeEvent()` method was modified to terminate the `thread` that was started.

How to make sure the `thread` is terminated only if it completed a task it was working on? What is the difference between stopping a thread with its `quit()` and its `terminate()` method? Should the `thread` always be terminated before the main application window is closed? Why on Mac OS X the `Python` process remains to be listed in Activity Monitor even after the main dialog is closed and the thread is terminated?

[image]

```
import threading
import Queue as Queue
import datetime

global queue
queue = Queue.Queue()


class Thread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, queue, parent):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            task = queue.get()
            output = task()
            queue.task_done()


def longToCalculate():
    for i in range(30000000):
        i += i
        if not i % 100000:
            print '%s ...still calculating ' % datetime.datetime.now()
    print 'calculation completed'
    return i


class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        # self.thread.quit()
        self.thread.terminate()
        event.accept()


class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()
        self.thread = Thread(queue=self.queue, parent=self)
        self.thread.start()
        queue.put(longToCalculate)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    dialog = Dialog()
    dialog.show()
    qApp.exec_()
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that calling `terminate()` will kill the thread (it depends on the platform). Calling `quit()` will do nothing if the thread isn't running an event-loop - and your example isn't. But even if it was, the thread can only exit once its `run()` method returns - which in your example means *never* (due to the infinite while-loop). Also: you have not provided a way to interrupt the long-running function, so the thread must always wait until it completes. There is no magic bullet that is guaranteed to kill a thread - you have to provide the exit strategy yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code which does not include Queue.

```
import os, sys
import datetime

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Thread( QThread ):
    def __init__( self, parent ):

        QThread.__init__( self, parent )

    def run( self ):
        self.longToCalculate()

    def longToCalculate( self ):
        for i in range( 30000000 ):
            i += i

            if ( i % 1000000 == 0 ):
                print( '%s ...still calculating' % QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString() )

        print( 'calculation completed' )
        return i

class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__( self, parent = None ):

        QDialog.__init__( self, parent )

        self.thread = Thread( parent = self )
        self.thread.start()

        self.thread.finished.connect( self.threadComplete )

    def threadComplete( self ) :
        QMessageBox.information( self, "Thread complete", "The thread has finished running. This program wil automatically close now." )
        self.close()

    def closeEvent( self, cEvent ) :

        if self.thread.isRunning() :
            QMessageBox.information( self, "Thread running", "The thread is running. You cannot close this program." )
            cEvent.ignore()

        else :
            cEvent.accept()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication( sys.argv )

    dialog = Dialog()
    dialog.show()

    qApp.exec_()
```